# Extract data from a list

Tags: plotting, list-manipulation

If I have the data (is a result from another code) as the following order how can I extract the first and the second elements to plot them?
I tried to put them in the table and matrix forms, but it doesn’t work.

```
   m= {{{0.02697, 0.07534, 2.01069*10^-7}}, {{0.02697, 0.07539, 
   1.93528*10^-7}}, {{0.02697, 0.07544, 1.86169*10^-7}}, {{0.02697, 
   0.07549, 1.78992*10^-7}}, {{0.02697, 0.07554, 
   1.71997*10^-7}}, {{0.02697, 0.07559, 1.65187*10^-7}}, {{0.02702, 
   0.07564, 1.57983*10^-7}}, {{0.02702, 0.07569, 
   1.508*10^-7}}, {{0.02702, 0.07574, 1.43801*10^-7}}, {{0.02702, 
   0.07579, 1.36986*10^-7}}, {{0.02702, 0.07584, 
   1.30357*10^-7}}, {{0.02702, 0.07589, 1.23913*10^-7}}, {{0.02702, 
   0.07594, 1.17657*10^-7}}, {{0.02702, 0.07599, 
   1.11589*10^-7}}, {{0.02702, 0.07604, 1.0571*10^-7}}, {{0.02702, 
   0.07609, 1.00021*10^-7}}, {{0.02702, 0.07614, 
   9.45223*10^-8}}, {{0.02702, 0.07619, 8.92153*10^-8}}, {{0.02702, 
   0.07624, 8.41009*10^-8}}, {{0.02702, 0.07629, 
    7.91802*10^-8}}, {{0.02702, 0.07634, 7.44542*10^-8}}, {{0.02702, 
    0.07639, 6.99239*10^-8}}, {{0.02702, 0.07644, 
   6.55905*10^-8}}, {{0.02702, 0.07649, 6.14549*10^-8}}, {{0.02702, 
   0.07654, 5.75185*10^-8}}, {{0.02707, 0.07659, 
  5.30937*10^-8}}, {{0.02707, 0.07664, 4.87648*10^-8}}, {{0.02707, 
  0.07669, 4.46342*10^-8}}, {{0.02707, 0.07674, 
  4.07032*10^-8}}, {{0.02707, 0.07679, 3.69729*10^-8}}, {{0.02707, 
  0.07684, 3.34445*10^-8}}, {{0.02707, 0.07689, 
  3.01192*10^-8}}, {{0.02707, 0.07694, 2.69983*10^-8}}, {{0.02707, 
  0.07699, 2.4083*10^-8}}, {{0.02707, 0.07704, 
  2.13745*10^-8}}, {{0.02707, 0.07709, 1.88743*10^-8}}, {{0.02707, 
  0.07714, 1.65837*10^-8}}, {{0.02707, 0.07719, 
  1.4504*10^-8}}, {{0.02707, 0.07724, 1.26367*10^-8}}, {{0.02707, 
  0.07729, 1.09831*10^-8}}, {{0.02707, 0.07734, 
  9.54488*10^-9}}, {{0.02707, 0.07739, 8.32337*10^-9}}, {{0.02712, 
  0.07744, 7.11523*10^-9}}, {{0.02712, 0.07749, 
  5.46072*10^-9}}, {{0.02712, 0.07754, 4.0217*10^-9}}, {{0.02712, 
  0.07759, 2.79968*10^-9}}, {{0.02712, 0.07764, 
  1.79621*10^-9}}, {{0.02712, 0.07769, 1.01288*10^-9}}, {{0.02712, 
  0.07774, 4.51297*10^-10}}, {{0.02712, 0.07779, 
   1.13109*10^-10}}, {{0.02712, 0.07784, 0.}}, {{0.02712, 0.07789, 
  1.13687*10^-10}}, {{0.02712, 0.07794, 4.55922*10^-10}}, {{0.02712, 
  0.07799, 1.02849*10^-9}}, {{0.02712, 0.07804, 
  1.83322*10^-9}}, {{0.02712, 0.07809, 2.87197*10^-9}}, {{0.02712, 
  0.07814, 4.14663*10^-9}}, {{0.02712, 0.07819, 
  5.65913*10^-9}}, {{0.02717, 0.07824, 7.25524*10^-9}}, {{0.02717, 
  0.07829, 8.2781*10^-9}}, {{0.02717, 0.07834, 
  9.53713*10^-9}}, {{0.02717, 0.07839, 1.10343*10^-8}}, {{0.02717, 
  0.07844, 1.27717*10^-8}}, {{0.02717, 0.07849, 
  1.47514*10^-8}}, {{0.02717, 0.07854, 1.69753*10^-8}}, {{0.02717, 
  0.07859, 1.94458*10^-8}}};
```

Comment: `ListPlot[m[[All, 1, 1 ;; 2]]]`. Please read the docs of [`Part`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Part.html).

Comment: you should review the code that creates this as it appears to be leaving you with an extra layer of `{  }` list delimiters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can eliminate the extraneous list level with one of:

```
m = Partition[Flatten[m],3]
m = m[[All,1]]
```

The first and second elements can then be plotted with:

```
ListPlot[m[[All,{1,2}]]]
```